# How to count occurrence of substring elements in string in python (even when repeated)?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried the following code

```
s = "BANANA"
print(s.count('ANA'))
>> 1
```

The output was 1. It did not consider A which was previously counted. 
I want the output to be 2 since 'ANA' occurs twice. Ia their a function I don't know about.

Comment: If you want to count the length of the string, just do: `print( len(s) )` If you want to count 'ANA', just do `print(len('ANA'))`

Comment: I dont think you Understood my question. I want to check how many times the substring (Here: 'ANA') occurs between the string. Or How any times 'ANA' appears in the word 'BANANA ' @ezzzCash

Comment: Ohh I understand now. your question is very similar to a more complex question that I asked a few days ago. The only difference is my question is dealing with integers rather than strings. However, the logic is still the same. Please the answer located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581326/given-a-string-of-a-million-numbers-return-all-repeating-3-digit-numbers