# Is it possible to popcount __m256i and store result in 8 32-bit words instead of the 4 64-bit using Wojciech Mula algorithm's?

Tags: c++, intel, sse, avx, avx2

I have recently discovered that AVX2 doesn't have a popcount for __m256i and the only way I found to do something similar is to follow the Wojciech Mula algorithm's:

```
__m256i count(__m256i v) {
    __m256i lookup = _mm256_setr_epi8(0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2,
                     2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3,
                     1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4);
    __m256i low_mask = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x0f);
    __m256i lo =_mm256_and_si256(v,low_mask);
    __m256i hi = _mm256_and_si256( _mm256_srli_epi32(v, 4), low_mask);
    __m256i popcnt1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup,lo);
    __m256i popcnt2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup,hi);
    __m256i total = _mm256_add_epi8(popcnt1,popcnt2);

    return _mm256_sad_epu8(total,_mm256_setzero_si256());
}
```

[Wojciech Muła, Nathan Kurz, Daniel Lemire, Faster Population Counts Using AVX2 Instructions, Computer Journal 61 (1), 2018](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07612.pdf)

The problem is that it return me the sum of 8 short into long instead of the sum of 4 short into int.

**What's currently happening:**
I have __m256i x which contain those 8 32-bit int:

1. 01101011111000011100000000000000
2. 01110101011010010111100000000000
3. 10100100011011000101010000000000
4. 11101010100001001111000000000000
5. 10010011111111001001010000000000
6. 00011110101100101000000000000000
7. 00011101011000111011000000000000
8. 10011011100010100000110000000000

__m256i res = count(x);

res contain:

1. 24
2. 21
3. 22
4. 21

The result is 4 long 64-bit

**Expectation:**

I have __m256i x which contain thoses 8 32-bit int:

1. 01101011111000011100000000000000
2. 01110101011010010111100000000000
3. 10100100011011000101010000000000
4. 11101010100001001111000000000000
5. 10010011111111001001010000000000
6. 00011110101100101000000000000000
7. 00011101011000111011000000000000
8. 10011011100010100000110000000000

__m256i res = count(x);

res contain:

1. 11
2. 13
3. 10
4. 11
5. 12
6. 9
7. 11
8. 10

The result is 8 int 32-bit.

Hope I was clear, don't hesitate to ask me for more precision.

Thanks.

Comment: This https://github.com/kimwalisch/libpopcnt may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AVX-512VPOPCNTDQ has [`_mm256_popcnt_epi32`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX_512,Other&text=vpopcnt&ig_expand=5420,5420) to popcount in 32-bit chunks, also a 64-bit chunk size version.  Outside of Xeon Phi, it's [new in Ice Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512) which also introduced AVX512BITALG which also has byte and word (16-bit) chunk sizes of `vpopcnt`.

---

#### With AVX2

The original code you are quoting relies on the `_mm256_sad_epu8` intrinsic, and it is specifically for summing up bytes within 64-bit words.

To get the same result, with sums of 32-bit words, you need to do something slightly different. The following should work:

```c
__m256i popcount_pshufb32(__m256i v) {

  __m256i lookup = _mm256_setr_epi8(0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2,
                 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3,
                 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4);
  __m256i low_mask = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x0f);
  __m256i lo = _mm256_and_si256(v, low_mask);
  __m256i hi = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi16(v, 4), low_mask);
  __m256i popcnt1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup, lo);
  __m256i popcnt2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup, hi);
  __m256i sum8 = _mm256_add_epi8(popcnt1, popcnt2);
  return _mm256_srli_epi32(
      _mm256_mullo_epi32(sum8, _mm256_set1_epi32(0x01010101)), 24);
      // vpmulld is slowish (2 uops) on most recent Intel CPUs
      // but still single-uop on AMD
}
```

So we replaced `_mm256_sad_epu8` by a multiplication and a shift. That should be reasonable. In my tests, [it is slightly slower than the original 64-bit version, but the difference is relatively small](https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/blob/master/extra/simd/popcount/avxpop.c).

You can get slightly better performance on Intel at the cost of one more vector constant, by using a different two instructions to accumulate from bytes to 32-bit chunks.  AMD Zen1/2/3 is at least as efficient with the above version as below.

32-bit SIMD-integer multiply is 2 uops on recent Intel CPUs (both for the SIMD-integer-multiply units), but the pairwise multiply-accumulate instructions (8->16 and 16->32) are a single uop each. (https://uops.info/) This requires one more constant, but the same number of instructions, for fewer uops especially if the compiler can reuse the constants in a loop.

```c
__m256i popcount_pshufb32(__m256i v) {

  __m256i lookup = _mm256_setr_epi8(0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2,
                 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3,
                 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4);
  __m256i low_mask = _mm256_set1_epi8(0x0f);
  __m256i lo = _mm256_and_si256(v, low_mask);
  __m256i hi = _mm256_and_si256(_mm256_srli_epi16(v, 4), low_mask);
  __m256i popcnt1 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup, lo);
  __m256i popcnt2 = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(lookup, hi);
  __m256i sum8 = _mm256_add_epi8(popcnt1, popcnt2);
  return _mm256_madd_epi16(_mm256_maddubs_epi16(sum8, _mm256_set1_epi8(1)),
                       _mm256_set1_epi16(1));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `_mm256_mul_epi32` is going to work? It neglects bits 32-63. I would expect a `_mm256_mullo_epi32` instead of  `_mm256_mul_epi32`. Note that `_mm256_mullo_epi32` is quite slow on Intel. A horizontal sum with shift-add-shift-add-mask_0xFF might be as fast.

Comment: After reading Agner Fog's instruction tables more carefully I think that the multiplication idea is probably faster than repeated shifting and adding, at least for Intel, maybe not for AMD Ryzen.

Comment: @wim: `vpmulld` is 2 dependent uops on Intel AVX2 CPUs, 10c latency.  Better to go from 8->16->32 with `pmaddubsw` and `pmaddwd`, with multipliers of `_mm256_set1_epi8(1)` and `_mm256_set1_epi16(1)`.  Same number of multiply uops, but you don't need the `srli`

Comment: @PeterCordes: That is a nice solution for the horizontal sum. I wasn't aware of this particular series of instructions.

Comment: @wim: credit to @PaulR, I think I picked that up from one of his answers.  (But normally `psadbw` is better if you want to go all the way to a 64-bit horizontal sum, unless you're doing something like [How to implement atoi using SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35127060) where you scale different elements by different amounts.)

Comment: @DanielLemire @wim Thanks a lot both of you ! It's work well with `_mm256_mullo_epi32` !

Comment: I wonder if there's anything to gain from masking the pshufb results (or `vpblendd` with zeros) and doing `psadbw` twice, once for the odd dwords, once for the even dwords.  But then you'd need to shuffle those results together, like `vpsllq`/`vpblendd`, unless a single shuffle can do it?  `vshufps` can grab the dwords you want, but not put them in the desired order.