# Using SIMD in lexical analysis

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, simd, lexer, lexical-analysis

I heard that modern compilers (clang) and parsers (like simdjson) use simd instructions to speed up lexing. But how is it possible?

I wanna to implement a lexer for a language in C++. How can I use simd to speed up Lexing and parsing?

Comment: One use of SIMD in RapidJSON is [How to implement atoi using SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35127060).  But that's not lexing.  Presumably x86 SSE2 `pcmpeqb` / `pmovmskb` can be useful to look for a space in 16 bytes at once.  Or SSE4.2 `pcmpistri/m` to get a bitmask of matches for char ranges or sets.  https://www.strchr.com/strcmp_and_strlen_using_sse_4.2.  Of course once you have a bitmask, you can bit-scan it.

Comment: GCC uses SIMD to speed up finding the end of a comment. Given the fact that between licenses, changelogs and documentation, it's quite possible that the majority of some files can be comments, I guess it makes sense. But I haven't seen (or searched for) a benchmark which confirms the effectiveness

Comment: Anyway, lexical analysis is not the bottleneck in compilation, and optimisation is best left for after you get the basics working. Just a suggestion.

Comment: rici - that's true but I found the question interesting, since I've been looking for ways to possibly do DFA implementations somehow without conditional branching. i'm still not sure it's possible, but if anyone *has* implemented a lexer using simd i'd love to know. Just my $0.02

Comment: Well, In general i say, lets look at SIMD as a tool. not all of languages are same, for example an nginx-like config file have just ten or twenty rules for language, but Python... is a complex one (may be more complex than C++). It seems that SIMD is just applicable for situations that we except a predefined expression, like a regex, specially for beginning and end of a string. so, consider SIMD for well-defined situations.