# Is there a fast way to convert a string of 8 ASCII decimal digits into a binary number?

Tags: c++, parsing, simd, avx2, atoi

Consider 8 digit characters like `12345678` as a string. It can be converted to a number where every byte contains a digit like this:

```
const char* const str = "12345678";
const char* const base = "00000000";
const uint64_t unpacked = *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(str)
    - *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(base);
```

Then `unpacked` will be `0x0807060504030201` on a little-endian system.

What is the fastest way to convert the number into `12345678`, perhaps by multiplying it by some magic number or using SIMD up to AVX2?

UPDATE: `12345678` has to be a number stored in a 32-bit or 64-bit integer, not a string.

Comment: Have a look at `_mm_maddubs_epi16` and `_mm_madd_epi16`

Comment: First step write test (to check validity), second step write performance test (to check speed) - this step is quite hard. Then do experiments. Writing code and assuming it is correct and fastest often leads of track.

Comment: *"UPDATE: 12345678 has to be a number stored in a 32-bit or 64-bit integer, not a string."* UNclear what is your input, if you have your number stored as `uin64_t`, then you don't have conversion to have `uin64_t`...

Comment: @Jarod42, the input is a string, it's in the code snippet in the question. I'm simply looking for an optimization of parsing a string into an integer.

Comment: So your are looking for [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars)?

Comment: See [How to implement atoi using SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35127060) for some ideas about using `pmaddwd` (and possibly `pmaddubsw`) with a vector of `[1,10,1,10,...]` for pairs of digits.  That Q&A is considering variable-length digit strings, though, IIRC, so it does more work.

Comment: Your title is really misleading here.  You're not *packing* (like BCD), you're converting an ASCII string of decimal digits to a binary integer.  That's not just packing.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplication in binary is just a series of shift & adds. A SWAR approach
shouldn't be too hard to understand. For a detailed walk-thru see:

- https://johnnylee-sde.github.io/Fast-numeric-string-to-int/
- https://kholdstare.github.io/technical/2020/05/26/faster-integer-parsing.html
- https://lemire.me/blog/2022/01/21/swar-explained-parsing-eight-digits/
- http://0x80.pl/articles/simd-parsing-int-sequences.html

```
// http://govnokod.ru/13461
static inline
uint32_t parse_8digits_swar_classic (char* str) {
    uint64_t v;

    memcpy(&v, str, 8);
    v = (v & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F) * 2561 >> 8;
    v = (v & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) * 6553601 >> 16;
    v = (v & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) * 42949672960001 >> 32;
    return v;
}

// attempt to improve the latency
static inline
uint32_t parse_8digits_swar_aqrit (char* str) {
    const uint64_t mask = 0x000000FF000000FF;
    uint64_t v, t;

    memcpy(&v, str, 8);
    v = (v * 10) + (v >> 8);
    t = (v & mask) * 0x000F424000000064;
    v = ((v >> 16) & mask) * 0x0000271000000001;
    v = (v + t + 0xFF0915C600000000ULL) >> 32;
    return v;
}

// SSSE3 needs less `shift & mask` operations...
static inline
uint32_t parse_8digits_simd_ssse3 (char* str) {
    const __m128i mul1 = _mm_set_epi32(0, 0, 0x010A0A64, 0x14C814C8);
    const __m128i mul2 = _mm_set_epi32(0, 0, 0x0001000A, 0x00FA61A8);
    const __m128i mask = _mm_set1_epi8(0x0F);
    __m128i v;

    v = _mm_loadl_epi64((__m128i*)(void*)str);
    v = _mm_and_si128(v, mask);
    v = _mm_madd_epi16(_mm_maddubs_epi16(mul1, v), mul2);
    v = _mm_add_epi32(_mm_add_epi32(v, v), _mm_shuffle_epi32(v, 1));
    return (uint32_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si32(v);
}
```

Comment: I thought this problem looked familiar; googling on that `0x010A0A64` constant found [SIMD string to unsigned int parsing in C# performance improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66371621) which you answered.

Answer (score 1):

On an older x86-64 system without AVX2, this simple version based on gathering digits in tree fashion is quite efficient, with performance on par with a simple SWAR-based implementation per my measurements. This requires a processor with a lot of instruction-level parallelism however, as it comprises 50% more instructions than the SWAR -based code when compiled with full optimizations.

```cpp
/* convert a string of exactly eight 'char' into a 32-bit unsigned integer */
uint32_t string_to_number (const char * s)
{
    uint32_t t0 = s[0] * 10 + s[1];
    uint32_t t1 = s[2] * 10 + s[3];
    uint32_t t2 = s[4] * 10 + s[5];
    uint32_t t3 = s[6] * 10 + s[7];
    uint32_t s0 = t0 * 100 + t1;
    uint32_t s1 = t2 * 100 + t3;
    uint32_t num = s0 * 10000 + s1;
    uint32_t corr =
        '0' * 10000000 +
        '0' * 1000000 +
        '0' * 100000 +
        '0' * 10000 +
        '0' * 1000 +
        '0' * 100 +
        '0' * 10 +
        '0' * 1;
    return num - corr;
}
```

Comment: Did you compare it against aqrit's SSSE3 version?  For a single integer, it does only need SSSE3, and can do 2 in parallel.  (It's highly throughput-optimized, about 8 uops.  Not counting loading vector constants.  Still not *bad* for latency either, but all the uops dependent on each other, including two SIMD integer multiplies, except for a `paddd` / `pshufd` pair.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I did not compare it because I did not see it until you pointed it out. I was mostly curious about the SWAR approach, because the simple tree approach needs only simple, high-throughput operations, except for three `IMUL`.

Comment: Fair enough.  How did you test (I assume throughput not latency converting stuff in a loop)?  And on what hardware?  Zen / Ice Lake have wider pipelines than previous x86, and have more execution units that handle LEA which I assume compilers will use a lot of, e.g. 2 for each `x * 10 + y` operation.

Comment: AArch64 is interesting for the SWAR versions; it can encode immediates for bitwise ops like AND as repeating bit-patterns, unlike x86-64 needing clunky 10-byte instructions.  https://godbolt.org/z/c1EPsdW5K.  For your version, clang chooses to use a lot of `madd` instructions, some with a constant 10.  But AArch64 probably can use SIMD efficiently for something similar to what we can do with SSSE3, probably even baseline unlike SSSE3.

Comment: @PeterCordes (1) Throughput; (2) Ivybridge, I  think; (3) Intel compiler. As godbolt shows, Clang, gcc, and icc produce pretty similar code when targeting generic x86-64, unsurprisingly dominated by `movsx` and 2-operand `lea`, both with throughput of 2/cycle on all(?) Intel CPUs of the past ten years per Agner Fog's tables. The total number of instructions is 22 or 23. Compilers realize one can get by with one `lea` per `movsx`  (e.g. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/P61aGr3f6))

Comment: LEA has 4/clock throughput on Ice Lake, 5/clock on Alder Lake P-cores (https://uops.info).  Before that, yes, 2/clock for non-slow LEA (`reg+reg*scale`, but `[reg+reg*scale+disp]` is only port 1).  MOVSX is handled purely in the load ports on Intel including IvB, but some CPUs have more efficient MOVZX than MOVSX, so `unsigned char` could be a good idea.  And yeah, 1 LEA per MOV[ZS]X is 2 LEAs per `x * 10 + y` where both x and y are ASCII chars that need extension from byte to dword.  `x *= 5` and `x * 2 + y` as in [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548057)

Comment: So you're right to do the correction at the end, instead of tempting compilers into using `lea     eax, [rax + 4*rax - 5*'0']` along the way.  That would save instructions, but cost code-size and limit it to 1 LEA per clock on Intel before ICL.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry still before first coffee. Yes, 1 `lea` per `movsx` <=> 2 `lea` per `*10`, so we are saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your input format to breadth-first element order like this:

```
Sample 9 numbers, interleaved
digit[]:
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
... 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ....

for(int j=0; j<num_parse; j+=9)
{
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        value[i] += 
          (multiplier[i]*=10)*
          (digit[i+j]-'0');
    }
    // value vector copied to output
    // clear value & multiplier vectors
}
```

And if you convert more than just 9 values, like 512 or 8192 with padding to any multiple of 32, compiler should vectorize it.

To prepare input, you can use 8 different channels, 1 per digit of every parsed value.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a small program to test some ideas. AVX2 implementation is ~1.5 times faster than the naive, with the table implementation in the middle:

```
AVX2: 12345678 in 3.42759
Naive: 12345678 in 5.12581
Table: 12345678 in 4.49478
```

Source code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const __m256i mask = _mm256_set1_epi32(0xf);
const __m256i mul = _mm256_setr_epi32(10000000, 1000000, 100000, 10000, 1000, 100, 10, 1);

const volatile char* str = "12345678";
volatile uint32_t h;

const int64_t nIter = 1000LL * 1000LL * 1000LL;

inline void parse_avx2() {
  const char* const base = "00000000";
  const uint64_t unpacked = *reinterpret_cast<const volatile uint64_t*>(str)
    - *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(base);

  const __m128i a = _mm_set1_epi64x(unpacked);
  const __m256i b = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi32(a);
  const __m256i d = _mm256_mullo_epi32(b, mul);
  const __m128i e = _mm_add_epi32(_mm256_extractf128_si256(d, 0), _mm256_extractf128_si256(d, 1));
  const uint64_t f0 = _mm_extract_epi64(e, 0);
  const uint64_t f1 = _mm_extract_epi64(e, 1);
  const uint64_t g = f0 + f1;
  h = (g>>32) + (g&0xffffffff);
}

inline void parse_naive() {
  const char* const base = "00000000";
  const uint64_t unpacked = *reinterpret_cast<const volatile uint64_t*>(str)
    - *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(base);

  const uint8_t* a = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&unpacked);
  h = a[7] + a[6]*10 + a[5]*100 + a[4]*1000 + a[3]*10000 + a[2]*100000 + a[1]*1000000 + a[0]*10000000;
}

uint32_t summands[8][10];
inline void parse_table() {
  const char* const base = "00000000";
  const uint64_t unpacked = *reinterpret_cast<const volatile uint64_t*>(str)
    - *reinterpret_cast<const uint64_t*>(base);

  const uint8_t* a = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&unpacked);
  h = summands[7][a[0]] + summands[6][a[1]] + summands[5][a[2]] + summands[4][a[3]]
    + summands[3][a[4]] + summands[2][a[5]] + summands[1][a[6]] + summands[0][a[7]];
}

int main() {
  clock_t start = clock();
  for(int64_t i=0; i<nIter; i++) {
    parse_avx2();
  }
  clock_t end = clock();
  cout << "AVX2: " << h << " in " << double(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

  start = clock();
  for(int64_t i=0; i<nIter; i++) {
    parse_naive();
  }
  end = clock();
  cout << "Naive: " << h << " in " << double(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;

  uint32_t mul=1;
  for(int i=0; i<8; i++, mul*=10) {
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++) {
      summands[i][j] = j*mul;
    }
  }

  start = clock();
  for(int64_t i=0; i<nIter; i++) {
    parse_table();
  }
  end = clock();
  cout << "Table: " << h << " in " << double(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unpacking to 32-bit right away is quite slow; `vpmulld` is 2 uops on Intel CPUs from Haswell onward (ones which support AVX2).  It's also unnecessary to broadcast `unpacked` before using only the low 64 bits of it anyway.  And `*reinterpret_cast<const volatile uint64_t*>` is a pretty inefficient way to maybe work around the strict-aliasing undefined behaviour (if it works at all), instead of using a `movq` intrinsic like `_mm_loadl_epi64` and SIMD `_mm_and_si128` or `_mm_sub_epi8` to get 0..9 integer digits out of the ASCII characters.