# How to convert a string to number in assembly language 8086?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am beginner in assembly and I need help for this conversion.The code below should convert from a string read from keyboard with the interrupt 01h.I know it is incorrect but can you help me identify the mistake?

```
mov dx,0 
convert:
    sub al,48 ;to covert to int
    mov bl,al ;in bl will be the digit read 
    mov ax,dx
    mul ten   ;ax will store the old result multiplied by 10
    mov bh,0
    add ax,bx
    mov dx,ax
```

Comment: Read this -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/19462538/4117717

Comment: This is not a good question. In fact, it is not a question at all. Please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Where is the pointer to the string? What is the expected output, and what is the output you are getting?

Comment: i don't understand what's going on in that code sorry.I wanted to make a loop there or a jump but the operand type don't mach i think.When i multiply by 10 ax,the result will be stored in dx:ax and i don't know how to handle this

Comment: now is a question,Ruud!

Comment: "I know it is incorrect" is not a good problem description; consequently "can you help me identify the mistake" is not a good question. But I am in a good mood and I managed to compose an answer (HTH), based on info you provided in your comments. Please edit your question to include the essential parts of the comments.

Comment: I'm so sorry I don't know how to ask a good question... Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

```
mul ten   ;ax will store the old result multiplied by 10
```

From the comment I understand that **ten** is a word sized variable containing the value 10.
This means that the multiply is word sized and thus overwrites DX.
Solution : Change DX to p.e. CX

```
mov cx,0 
convert:
sub al,48 ;to covert to int
mov bl,al ;in bl will be the digit read 
mov ax,cx
mul ten   ;ax will store the old result multiplied by 10
mov bh,0
add ax,bx
mov cx,ax
```

Comment: If you load new characters into a different register (not AX), the total can stay in AX for `total = total*10 +  (char - '0')` across loop iterations.  This appears to have way move `mov` instructions than necessary.  And you can even use DX for the temporary for zero-extending a new character, after `mul` clobbers it.

Comment: [connecting integer multiplication in assembly x86](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74709668) has a loop that uses 16-bit multiply and add.

Answer (score 0):

`mul` comes in 2 flavors:

- multiply two 8-bit values (`AL` and `mul`'s operand); store the 16-bit result in `AX`
- multiply two 16-bit values (`AX` and `mul`'s operand); store the 32-bit result in `DX AX`

Your question is a bit vague, but I assume you *want* the first flavor, but instead you found yourself faced with the second.

To tell the assember you want the first flavor, give `mul` an operand that is **unmistakably** 8-bit. One way that certainly works on all assemblers, is to use an 8-bit register, for example `BH` (I chose that one because it is obvious its value is irrelevant at the time of `mul` since it is overwritten shortly after).

```
sub al,48   ; to covert to int
mov bl,al   ; in bl will be the digit read 
mov ax,dx

mov bh,10   ; use BH to hold factor 10
mul bh      ; multiply AL by BH; the product is stored in AX; DX is unaffected

mov bh,0
add ax,bx
mov dx,ax
```

**EDIT:**
I just realized this will limit the range of numbers that can be entered to 0...255, which is probably *not* what you want. Use user3628942's solution instead; it allows you to enter numbers up to 65535.

As often, there are other ways. Below is a solution that uses `add` instead of `mul`. Many years ago, this was a popular trick for processor architectures where `mul` was either an expensive (i.e. slow) instruction, or totally absent. Works for numbers up to 65535; silently wraps to zero for higher numbers.

```
sub al,48    ; ASCII value --> numeric value
mov ah,0     ; AX = numeric value of digit
add dx,dx    ; DX = 2 * original DX
add ax,dx    ; AX = 2 * original DX + digit
add dx,dx    ; DX = 4 * original DX
add dx,dx    ; DX = 8 * original DX
add dx,ax    ; DX = 10 * original DX + digit
```