# how to write a converter from a numeric value to a string value on tasm?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I need to do some task using TASM, but for it i need to work with input numbers.
So first of all i'm trying to enter number into the console, then convert this string value to numeric value, and then convert this numeric value back into string value to output it to the console. I just want to be sure, that converters work right.
it may sound silly ( ' ^') , but such checks will be useful to me in my actual task

this is a converter that at least performs the smallest part of the functionality of all my other options :c It probably works only for number from 0 to 9, but not higher.
The result is on image (first line is our input number, than on second line is amount of characters, than our converted input number is on the third line. the first and the third lines must be equal)

[image: the result of converters]

```
mov ah, 0
mov si, offset counter_buffer 
push cx
convert_counter_to_ascii:
    mov dx, 0
    mov ax, cx
    mov bx, 10
    div bx
    add dl, '0'
    dec si
    mov [si], dl
    mov cx, ax
    cmp cx, 0 
    jnz convert_counter_to_ascii

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, si
    int 21h
```

and this's my full program to see the context:

````
assume cs: code, ds: data, ss: stck
code segment
begin:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax

    ;buffered input
    mov ah, 0ah
    mov dx, offset first_input
    int 21h

    ;finding the end of an input string
    mov bx, 0
    mov bl, [first_input + 1]
    mov first_input[bx + 2], '$'
    
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, 0dh
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h

    ;set index counter
    mov di, 0

;counting the amount of input characters. 
;for example: 234 -> total = 5 characters,
;because there're two control bytes in the beginning of buffered input
count_characters:
    mov al, first_input[di]
    cmp al, '$'
    je end_count
    inc di
    jmp count_characters

end_count:
    ;just saving the amount of input characters
    mov cx, di

    ;subtract two, because i'm only interested in numeric characters
    ;without first 2 control bytes
    sub cx, 2
;==================================================================================
;it's a converter of the numeric value of characters amount to string. 
;here i'm going just to check which value i'm actually getting, after "count_caharacters" cycle
;just to be sure that there isn't any mistake and see the result on the console

    mov ah, 0
    ;set si in the beginning of array "counter_buffer", where i'm going to
    ;save string value of counter value.
    mov si, offset counter_buffer 

    push cx

;i don't really sure that this converter is actually right,
;to say exactly it's probably works only for values from 0 to 9,
;but not higher. or not... help ( т _т)
convert_counter_to_ascii:
    mov dx, 0
    mov ax, cx
    mov bx, 10
    div bx
    add dl, '0'
    dec si
    mov [si], dl
    mov cx, ax
    cmp cx, 0 
    jnz convert_counter_to_ascii

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, si
    int 21h

;end of converting the numeric value of counter to string value
;=====================================================================================

    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, 0dh
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h

    pop cx

    ;subtracting one from the amount of characters 
    ;because i'm going to count the power of 10
    ;for example input: 234 => cx = 3
    ;234 = 200 + 30 + 4
    ;and because 4 (the last digit) doesn't multipling by any power of 10, 
    ;we are subtracting one character from cx => 
    ;cx = 2 => 10 ^ 2 = 100, and we will get the highest power of 10.
    sub cx, 1
    push cx
    
    ;if the input had only one numeric digit, after subtracting 
    ;1 from cx, we will get zero
    ;so here we just check it
    cmp cx, 0
    je just_one_digit
    
    cmp cx, 0
    jne pow_loop

;here we start the cycle to find the highest power of 
;10 of the input number (for 234 it's 10^2)
;works correctly till power up to 10^2 (only for three digit number), 
;but for current task it's ok
pow_loop:
    mov al, [digit_saver]
    mov bl, 10
    mul bl
    mov [digit_saver], al
    loop pow_loop

    pop cx

    ;returning the full amount of characters in cx by adding 1
    add cx, 1
    push cx

    ;di saves the amount of characters(address of last numeric character)
    mov di, cx
    ;we set index in 2 to avoid the first two control bytes, 
    ;and start converting numeric characters to it's actual numeric values
    mov si, 2

convert_string_to_number:
    ;check each element of input array
    mov al, first_input[si]
    ;we need to check that we're not going to multiply the last 
    ;digit by any power of 10, that's why
    ;we need this compare instruction.
    cmp si, di
    je just_one_digit
    inc si
    ;to get the actual numeric value from string value we need to 
    ;subtract ASCII code of '0' from it
    sub al, '0'
    ;mov the power of ten to bl, and then multiply the current numeric value to this power
    mov bl, [digit_saver]
    ;this instruction is multiplying the stored power of 10 in bl by the numeric value in al
    ;the final result is stored in al (as far as i understand multiplying)
    mul bl
    ;then i have a variable "real_first_number" which will store the 
    ;final summ (this sum: 200 + 30 + 4)
    mov bh, [real_first_number]
    ;add the result of multiplying to bg
    add bh, al
    ;set the value in bh back to "real_first_number"
    mov [real_first_number], bh
    loop convert_string_to_number
 
;it's a mark to sum the last digit, that doesn't need multiplying by power of 10
just_one_digit:
    ;cx saved the amount of numeric characters except first two control bytes
    mov si, cx
    ;here we add this two control bytes, to know exactly the position of this last digit
    ;(position of the last element)
    add si, 2
    ;then we convert it to numeric value
    mov al, first_input[si]
    sub al, '0'
    ;add to result sum. and now we have our entered number in numeric form
    mov bh, [real_first_number]
    add bh, al
    mov [real_first_number], bh


    ;here starts converiting this number that is in numeric form, 
    ;back to string, to output it to the console
    mov ah, 0
    ;array to save string value of this number
    mov si, offset first_number_buffer

    mov al, [real_first_number]
;and here is starting the converter in which i'm not sure.
;for some reason as i said above it works for numbers from 0 to 9,
;but if values os higher  - it brokes ( т _т) 
convert_counter_to_asc:
    mov dx, 0
    mov bx, 10
    div bx
    add dl, '0'
    dec si
    mov [si], dl
    mov cx, ax
    cmp cx, 0 
    jnz convert_counter_to_asc

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, si
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
code ends

data segment
    first_input db 10, ?, 10 dup (?)
    real_first_number db 0
    first_number_buffer db 6 dup ('$')

    counter_buffer db 6 dup('$')

    digit_saver db 1
data ends

stck segment stack
    db 256 dup(?)
stck ends

end begin```
````

Comment: Is this a question, or are you just sharing working code?  If the latter, put the code in an *answer* to a simple question.  e.g. like Sep did with the self-answered Q&A [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075) (which this question is a partial duplicate of).  Also [Multiplying arbitrarily long sequences of ASCII digits by a single-digit multiplier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74709668) and [How to convert a string to number in assembly language 8086?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27703166) have x86-16 string-to-integer.

Comment: good morning! i understood how to convert a string value to a numeric value. i can't get the block of code that i highlighted at the beginning, which is converting numeric value to a string value. and.. oh. i just wanted to write code in separate program, to show only functionality of this block of code, but found in the internet that the remainder of div operation is not in dl, it's stores in ah ( ' ^') now everything is working ))))) he he he sorry and thank you

Answer (score 0):

that's right, the numeric value was converted to a string value

```
.model small
.data 
    output_buffer db 10 dup(" ")  
.stack
  db 256 dup (?)
.code
  mov ax, @data    
  mov ds, ax
    
  mov al, 234
  mov cx, 3
  mov di, cx
  mov output_buffer[di], '$'

;before first iteration the value in al = 234
;and output_buffer[3] = '$'

;after first iteration the value in al = 23, and the value in ah = 4
;and output_buffer[2] = '4'
;after second iteration the value in al = 2, and the value in ah = 3
;and output_buffer[1] = '3'
;after third iteration the valuue in al = 0, and the value in ah = 2
;and output_buffer[0] = '2'
convert_integer_to_string:
  dec di
  mov ah, 0
  mov bl, 10
  div bl
  add ah, '0'
  mov output_buffer[di], ah
  cmp di, 0
  jne convert_integer_to_string

  ;and the result is: output_buffer = "234$" 
  mov ah, 09h
  mov dx, offset output_buffer
  int 21h

  mov ah, 4Ch   
  int 21h      
end
```