# Convert from ascii to integer in AT&T Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, ascii, att

How can I convert from ascii to integer?

```
    data

asd: 
    .int 32

.text

.globl _start

_start:

    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $1,(asd)
    add $48,(asd)
    movl $asd, %ecx
    movl $4, %edx
    int $0x80

    # Exit the program
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

The code is writing an ascii value, and I think that if I can add 48 to value. I can write, but I can't print, a two-stage number "for example 53 or 156". How can I print?

Comment: You have to do it one digit at a time. Divide by 10 to isolate the next digit.

Comment: NASM version of this: [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548057)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually best to think about a high level language version first. If the number has `n` digits and is stored in array `a`, then we'd want:

```
char *p = a;
unsigned val = 0;
while (n > 0) {
  n--;
  val = 10 * val + (*p++ - '0');
}
```

So let's say `%esi` is `p` above `%eax` is `val`, and `%ecx` is `n`.
Translate line by line to keep it as simplistic and literal as possible:

```
  movl $n, %ecx
  movl $a, %esi
  xorl %eax, %eax     # val = 0
eval_while_cond:
  testl %ecx, %ecx    # if (n <= 0) 
  jle done            #   goto done
  subl $1, %ecx       # n--
  movl %eax, %ebx     # tmp1 = val
  imul $10, %ebx      # tmp1 = 10 * tmp1
  movzbl (%esi), %eax # tmp2 = *p
  addl $1, %esi       # p++
  subl $'0, %eax      # tmp2 = tmp2 - '0'
  addl %eax, %ebx     # val = tmp2 + tmp1
  jmp eval_while_cond
done:
  # result is now in %eax
```

Note this is just a general methodology for getting functional assembly language. This isn't optimized in any way. The tricks needed to get optimal performance are a whole other topic.

The other options is to use a compiler (e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/WzGYjePzx) with light optimization like -O1, -Og, or -Os to get somewhat-readable asm (although in this case they use not-totally-obvious tricks with LEA to multiply by 10 and subtract `'0'` (`48`), or they make a mess with weird loop conditions.)  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

Comment: `mul` doesn't work with immediates, you want `imul`, and the comment character in AT&T syntax is `#`.  Also, prefer `test %ecx, %ecx` [instead of `or`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg).  See [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548057) for an efficient version of this loop.  (Except it stops on `*p` not being a digit, rather than using a counted loop.)