# Writing integer to console gives Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, assembly, io, nasm, 32-bit

Going from high to low lever language I got to assembly. Now at the very beginning, I wrote a simple age program (I'm not clear how to get system time yet so I just used another input). I get Segmentation Fault (core dumped) after I enter the final input. Here is my code:

```
section .text
global _start       

_start:                     

mov edx, lenask
mov ecx, ask
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 0x80

mov edx, 5
mov ecx, input
mov ebx, 2
mov eax, 3
int 0x80

mov edx, lenask2
mov ecx, ask2
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 0x80

mov edx, 5
mov ecx, input2
mov ebx, 2
mov eax, 3
int 0x80

mov eax, input2
mov ebx, input
sub eax, ebx

push eax

mov edx, lenanswer
mov ecx, answer
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 0x80

pop eax

mov edx, 7
mov ecx, eax
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 4
int 0x80

section .data

ask db "What is your age?"
lenask equ $-ask
ask2 db "What is today's year?"
lenask2 equ $-ask2
answer db "The age you were born was: "
lenanswer equ $-answer

section .bss 

input resb 5
input2 resb 5
```

An example of what happens:

```
What is your age?45
What is today's year?2015
The age you were born was: Segmentation fault
```

It should have done:

```
What is your age?45
What is today's year?2015
The age you were born was: 1970
```

Comment: Why are you using `stderr` (2)  for input instead of `stdin` (0)?

Comment: The 7 should've been a 5, that's my bad, but it doesn't solve it. And for the stdin, I haven't thought of that, but changing it to 0 still doesn't help

Comment: The issue is that the `int $0x80` system call for writing to a file requires a pointer to a string buffer to print be placed in _ECX_ . When you print out the result you attempt to do this `mov ecx, eax`. You moved the calculated value into _ECX_, but that is not a pointer. You need to convert the value in _EAX_ to the string representation of that value, and pass the address of that string in _ECX_ . An example of an integer to string conversion function (_int_to_string_) can be found in this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19312503/3857942).

Comment: You also need to do something similar when inputting. Read input returns a string pointer in _EAX_. You need to convert the strings you get into integers and then do subtraction.  Your subtraction simply subtracts the two pointers. The _string_to_int_ function in the same [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19312503/3857942) is an example of such a conversion.

Comment: @MichaelPetch That sounds a lot like an answer. Comments are not supposed to be used for answers; please avoid that, thanks.

Comment: @black   . I disagree in this case. This question is basically an indirect duplicate of the other Stackoverflow question, except the OP doesn't know the root cause of the issue. I don't answer the _HOW_ to convert. IMHO, the real answer they want is in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19312503/3857942 . That answer is NASM/Linux/32-bit, but the question is not technically a duplicate of this, but the answer would solve this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question comes down to converting string to integers (and integers to string) in NASM/Linux/32-Bit. This [StackOverflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19312503/3857942) would solve this question. The two questions aren't duplicates but the answer is.

Comment: @OzgurBar If you want to add an answer to this question, be my guest.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I don't think it's a _direct_ dup, as you say. Therefore, answer by telling the user what's wrong (that is, the actual problem -- missing int-to-string conversion in this case) and point them to a question where that's been already covered. That's the behavior I think works best in these cases.

Comment: I have informed the user that the answers they seek are in other SO Answers, via a comment, and since I'm not on SO for reputation, I don't need to place an answer that already exists elsewhere on this site. I recommend upvoting the other answer.

Comment: @MichaelPetch That must be the problem. I've ran the debugger just to check it again and it located the segmentation problem at 0x004014 of _start. While the actual start label is at instruction 0x004000. Does that mean anything special? And thank you for pointing me to the solution.

Comment: And I've corrected the input aswell, still the debugger says the error is at the mentioned location.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `int 0x80` with `eax` set to `4` calls the kernel's `sys_write` function (i.e. a `write` system call) which expects a pointer to a string. By providing a integer to the function call the kernel will think that the integer is a pointer to a memory location. Because `1970` is not a valid pointer it will raise a `-EFAULT`. To bypass this you need to code a `ToString` function to convert the number to a string and then pass the pointer to the converted string.

The Segmentation Fault itself is caused by not having a `sys_exit` call. The reason for this is that the program will continue past the end of your code (usally into a bunch of `00 00`)

Comment: EAX=4 / `int 0x80` is the [`write` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html).  Passing it a bad pointer will make it return `-EFAULT` because it's a system call; bad pointers to system calls don't directly raise SIGSEGV.  The fault here is from falling off the end of `.text`, often into some `00 00` bytes (`add [eax], al`, and EAX = `-EFAULT` isn't a valid pointer either.  But this time we're dereferencing in user-space).  Single-step it with a debugger to see.  [What happens if there is no exit system call in an assembly program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49674026)

Comment: Didn’t notice the lack of a sys_exit call. Fixed.