# Assembly 8086 read number from keyboard

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, emu8086

How can I read number from keyboard(assume that the number can be from 0 to 65535) and put value in AX register using DOS interface? Result should be same as if we would just write `MOV ax, 65535` for example. I tried to do it by myself, but it didn't worked out. I'd like to see a code as an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert String to Number in 8086 assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979870/how-to-convert-string-to-number-in-8086-assembly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't straightforward in assembly. You'll need to make use of routines provided by either the OS or the BIOS in order to read a character and then build on top of this.

You've tagged the question with `emu8086` which claims to have a DOS interface. In that case you can use `int 21h` with `ah` set to either 1 or 7 to read a character. You'll then have to check it's a valid number character and then loop around reading more values until done. There's a `int 21h` reference [here](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html) which should help.