# 64-bit assembly code to add 2 numbers

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have written this program in 64-bit assembly to add two numbers. It works for 1-digit numbers, but not for 2-digit numbers.

What is wrong with my code?

```
segment .data
  msg1 db "Enter a digit", 0xA, 0xD
  len1 equ $- msg1
  msg2 db "Please enter the second digit", 0xA, 0xD
  len2 equ $- msg2
  msg3 db "The sum is :"
  len3 equ $- msg3

segment .bss
  num1 resb 2
  num2 resb 2
  res resb 2

segment .text
global _start
_start:
  call _text1
  call _getName1
  call _text2
  call _getName2
  call _text3

  mov rax, [num1]
  sub rax, '0'

  mov rbx, [num2]
  sub rbx, '0'

  add rax, rbx
  add rax, '0'
  mov [res], rax
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, res
  mov rdx, 2
  syscall

  mov rax, 60
  mov rdi, 0
  syscall
_text1:
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, msg1
  mov rdx, len1
  syscall
  ret

_getName1:
  mov rax, 0
  mov rdi, 0
  mov rsi, num1
  mov rdx, 2
  syscall
  ret

_text2:
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, msg2
  mov rdx, len2
  syscall
  ret

_getName2:
  mov rax, 0
  mov rdi, 0
  mov rsi, num2
  mov rdx, 2
  syscall
  ret

_text3:
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, msg3
  mov rdx, len3
  syscall
  ret
```

Comment: Writing 3 versions of the same function instead of just passing 3 different args to the same function completely defeats the purpose of having functions.

Comment: Anyway, note the difference between `"10"` (two characters) and 10 + the ASCII code for `'0'`.  That's of course still a single-digit ASCII code.  You need to a function that can convert an integer to a string, and this has been asked hundreds of times on SO.

Comment: To @PeterCordes point, look up `itoa` (integer to ascii) conversion routines written in assembly -OR- call the C runtime function of same name.

Comment: BTW, there are many more bugs, like not enough memory space reserved for `num1` and `num2`... you completely lack any idea how values are stored in computer and what is size of common data types. Read something about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the allotted memory space in

```
segment .bss
  num1 resb 2
  num2 resb 2
  res resb 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if number entered is greater than or equal to 9 then you need to sub rax,'07' or else you need to sub rax,'00'.

Comment: Subtracting `'42' - '00'` isn't the integer `42`, it's `0x0204`.  If you want to handle multi-digit numbers, you also need to multiply by their place values (10^n, not 256^n) and add.  [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548057).  Maybe you're talking about hex?  Like `'A' - '7'` being `10`?  Yes that works for single-digit hex, but there's no reason to subtract `'07'`, just `'7'`.  Or I'd write it as `sub eax, 'A'-10` to get the right semantic meaning for human readers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).