# ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE Help needed to make a comparison program

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I have been given a small assignment to make a small program in assembly now I am trying to make a grade calculator you input your marks and it tells you the grade

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
Msg1 db 'Enter your total marks from 0 to 99: $'
EightyPlus db 'Congratulation you have got an A $'
.code
start:
Mov ax,@data
Mov ds,ax

Mov ah,09
Lea dx,Msg1
int 21h

mov ah,02
mov dl,10
int 21h


mov ah,01
int 21h

mov bl,01
int 21h

cmp al, '8'
jl exit

;; true1: ;; we don't really need this label anymore, as it is not referenced
mov ah,02
mov dl,10
int 21h

Mov ah,09
Lea dx,[EightyPlus]
int 21h
;; now continue and exit

exit:
Mov ah,4ch
int 21h

end start
```

Now what I want is that if al input is greater than or equal to 8 it should print grade A but as of now it prints grade A on every input need some help here

The `bl` is just a gimmick to get two inputs from the user you can ignore it or help me to take more than one character input from user and do the task as I have asked above

EDIT: it was working through this code but now as I have used `bl` it does not work again

Comment: [How to input from a user multi digit number in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54696513)

Comment: checked it but I did not understand it I can leave for now but can you help me in making this comparison possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
mov al,01
int 21h

mov bl,01
int 21h
```

The DOS function to read a character from standard input is `int 21h` with `ah  = 01h`.  See http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm.  You have never initialized `ah`.  And the `mov` to `bl` in between is pointless.

It sounds like you want to read a character and use it for your comparison, then read a second character and ignore it.  You could do something like:

```
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
mov bl, al
int 21h ; ah still contains 01, unless DOS is buggy
cmp bl, '8'
jge true1
```

A second bug is after `jge true1`.  Remember how a conditional jump works: it jumps if the condition is true, and if not, execution continues with the next instruction in memory.  In your program, the next instruction is ... the instruction right after the `true1` label.  So execution continues at `true1` regardless of whether the condition was true or false.

Sometimes beginners to assembly think that labels are like functions, and code will automatically "return" when it reaches a new label, as if it were the close brace of a function.  That's not true; labels just give you a human-readable way to refer to a particular address, and don't by themselves affect program flow at all.

If you want to skip the output of the `EightyPlus` string when the condition is false, then you need to jump over it:

```
cmp bl, '8'
jge true1
jmp exit

true1:
Mov ah,09
Lea dx,[EightyPlus]
int 21h
;; now continue and exit

exit:
Mov ah,4ch
int 21h
```

But you could do it more efficiently by reversing the test:

```
cmp bl, '8'
jl exit

;; true1: ;; we don't really need this label anymore, as it is not referenced
Mov ah,09
Lea dx,[EightyPlus]
int 21h
;; now continue and exit

exit:
Mov ah,4ch
int 21h
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation but the problem has just reversed itself before it would print grade A with any input and now it does not print it with any input where it is 8,9,2,4 etc

Comment: Please edit your question with your updated code, as well as the exact input that causes the problem (e.g. are you entering one digit or two?).

Comment: please check i have edited the question

Comment: @GhulamMustafa: I suggested `mov bl, al` but your program still has the incorrect `mov bl, 01`.  The `int 21h / ah = 01h` call returns the character in `al`.  We want to save it in `bl` because `al` will be overwritten by the following `int 21h` call.

Comment: so what should i do i am very stuck can not you make this program and send me the code?

Comment: @GhulamMustafa: **Take the line `mov bl,01` in your program and change it to `mov bl, al`.** That should be all you need to do.  No, I am not going to write your assigned program for you; that would be unethical.  On a similar note, when you turn in your assignment, you need to acknowledge that you got help and used code from this post.

Comment: i did it but now it shows grade A on the second input and I want it to depend on the first

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "second input" and "first input".  What is the *exact, complete* input you are giving the program that results in undesired output?

Comment: Thank you so much :)