# For what a "@" symbol in emu8086?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I wan't to ask, in `x86-16` assembly `@` symbol is for what ? Can you explain ?

Example :

```
.data
str db "Hello!", 6, 10, '$'

mov ax, @data ; <- here
mov ds, ax
```

Comment: The selector (address divided by 16 in real mode) for the given segment.

Comment: I don't know about emu8086 specifically, but with MASM `@data` is a predefined symbol that expands to `DGROUP`. And `DGROUP` is a 64k segment group which combines the _DATA, _BSS, CONST, and STACK segments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assembly code do not recognise ? and @data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57316059/5221149)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is assembly code for the [Microsoft Macro Assembler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/microsoft-macro-assembler-reference?view=vs-2019) (MASM).

[`.data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-data?view=vs-2019) defines the beginning of the data segment.

[`@data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/at-data?view=vs-2019) is the address of the data segment.

Which in this case means that the code is assigning the address of the "Hello!" string to the `ds` register.

Note: `data` is not a label you can choose, it is a keyword.

Comment: `@data` isn't "the address", it's the linear address right shifted by 4, i.e. the real-mode segment-register value the assembler expects to make `seg:off` addressing into `.data` work, for the `[offset]` values it uses in addressing modes.