# NASM Comparison Always Falls to Default

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I am "successfully" getting user input, however my `switchCase` function always falls to the `defaultCase`:

```
extern  printf      ; the C function, to be called

SECTION .data
    promptNVal: db 'Enter nth case number: ' ;Ask user for nth case number
    promptNValLen: equ $-promptNVal

    nvalue: dd 2
    val1: dd 4
    val2: dd 1024
    val3: dd 32767
    defaultMsg: db "Default: ", 0

    belowMinMsg: db "Number cannot be below 0.", 0
    aboveMaxMsg: db "Number cannot be above 65535.", 0

    intFmt0:    db "Case0: %d", 10, 0 ; The printf format, "\n",'0' for case 0
    intFmt1:    db "Case1: %d", 10, 0 ; The printf format, "\n",'0' for case 1
    intFmt2:    db "Case2: %d", 10, 0 ; The printf format, "\n",'0' for case 2
    intFmt3:    db "Case3: %d", 10, 0 ; The printf format, "\n",'0' for case 3
    strFmt: db "%s", 10, 0 ; The printf format, "\n",'0' for strings
    intValidationError: db "Error. Number entered was: %d", 10, 0 ; The printf format, "\n",'0' for strings

SECTION .text
global  main

main:
    push    ebp     ; set up stack frame
    mov     ebp,esp

    ;prompt nvalue
    mov eax, 4 
    mov ebx, 1     ; descriptor value for stdout
    mov ecx, promptNVal 
    mov edx, promptNValLen
    int 0x80
    
    ;Read and store nth number 
    mov eax, 3 
    mov ebx, 0     ; descriptor value for stdin
    mov ecx, nvalue
    mov edx, 10
    int 0x80 

    cmp eax, 0 ; check if nvalue if below 0
    jl belowMin ; print below 0 message in belowMin function
    cmp eax, 65535 ; check if nvalue if above 0
    jg aboveMax ; print above maximum message in aboveMax function
    jmp switchCase  ; otherwise, jump to switchCase
    
    case0:
        mov eax, [val1]   
        mov ebx, [val2]
        mul ebx
        push eax
        push    dword intFmt0   ; address of string for case0
        call    printf      ; Call C function
        add     esp, 12     ; pop stack 3 push times 4 bytes

        mov     esp, ebp    ; takedown stack frame
        pop     ebp     ; same as "leave" op
        call quit
    case1:
        mov eax, [val2]   
        mov ebx, [val3]
        mul ebx
        push eax
        push    dword intFmt1   ; address of string for case1
        call    printf      ; Call C function
        add     esp, 12     ; pop stack 3 push times 4 bytes

        mov     esp, ebp    ; takedown stack frame
        pop     ebp     ; same as "leave" op
        call quit
    case2:
        mov eax, [val3]   
        mov ebx, [val1]
        sub eax, ebx
        push eax
        push    dword intFmt2   ; address of string for case2
        call    printf      ; Call C function
        add     esp, 12     ; pop stack 3 push times 4 bytes

        mov     esp, ebp    ; takedown stack frame
        pop     ebp     ; same as "leave" op
        call quit
    case3: 
        mov eax, [val1]   
        mov ebx, [val3]
        sub eax, ebx
        push eax
        push    dword intFmt3   ; address of string for case3
        call    printf      ; Call C function
        add     esp, 12     ; pop stack 3 push times 4 bytes

        mov     esp, ebp    ; takedown stack frame
        pop     ebp     ; same as "leave" op
        call quit
    defaultCase:
        mov eax, defaultMsg    
        push    dword defaultMsg    ; value of variable defaultMsg
        push    dword strFmt    ; address of string for defaultCase
        call    printf      ; Call C function
        add     esp, 12     ; pop stack 3 push times 4 bytes

        mov     esp, ebp    ; takedown stack frame
        pop     ebp     ; same as "leave" op
        call quit

belowMin:
    mov eax, belowMinMsg    
    push    dword belowMinMsg   ; value of variable belowMinMsg
    push    dword strFmt    ; address of ctrl string
    call    printf      ; Call C function
    add     esp, 12     ; pop stack 3 push times 4 bytes

    mov     esp, ebp    ; takedown stack frame
    pop     ebp     ; same as "leave" op
    call quit

aboveMax:
    mov eax, aboveMaxMsg    
    push    dword aboveMaxMsg   ; value of variable aboveMaxMsg
    push    dword strFmt    ; address of ctrl string
    call    printf      ; Call C function
    add     esp, 12     ; pop stack 3 push times 4 bytes

    mov     esp, ebp    ; takedown stack frame
    pop     ebp     ; same as "leave" op
    call quit

switchCase:
    mov eax, [nvalue] ; get value of nvalue
    cmp eax, 0 ; check if nvalue is 0
    je case0 ; if case0 to case0 function
    cmp eax, 1  ; check if nvalue is 1
    je case1 ; if case1 to case1 function
    cmp eax, 2  ; check if nvalue is 2
    je case2 ; if case2 to case2 function
    cmp eax, 3  ; check if nvalue is 3
    je case3 ; if case3 to case3 function
    jmp defaultCase ; otherwise, go to defaultCase function

quit:
    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     eax, 1
    int     80h
    ret
```

The terminal output is always "Default: " no matter what I input for the `nvalue`. Why is this happening?

**UPDATE**

I've tried printing `nvalue` inside of `defaultCase` and looks like I'm getting 2608 for 0, 2609 for 1, 2610 for 2, 2611 for 3, etc.

Comment: There's at least two ways to handle this. (1) Single step and verify that each instruction has the effect you want, and you'll find where it first goes wrong -- fix that then repeat; (2) Write the shortest possible program that does each little thing you're trying to do, and when they're working, string them together in a next program. If it were me I would focus on the first `int 0x80` read call to verify that you're getting what you want in `nvalue` and/or `eax`.  Are you?

Comment: @ErikEidt No, I'm not. I removed all user inputs except for nvalue, and I'm printing it in the defaultCase. I'm getting 2608 when I input 0, 2609 for 1, 2610 for 2, and 2611 for 3. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: `2608 = 0x0A30` which due to endianness is `0x30 0x0A` which is ascii code for `0` and line feed. Meaning, `read()` gives you text, not numbers.

Comment: I see no debugging has happened, nor is this a minimal example, please update the question with a minimal example and indicate the debugging you did to try to isolate the problem.

Comment: @Jester I think I just need to convert ascii to integers then. what's the best way to implement that?

Comment: Looks like `add     esp, 12` is popping too much, saved only by `mov     esp, ebp` immediately overwriting ESP with the correct value.  (But still leaves a 1 instruction window where a signal handler could step on a stack value.)

Comment: See the multi-digit number FAQ entry in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info, specifically [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548057).  (Or call `atoi` if you want to let the C library do it for you, or use `scanf` instead of making a raw `read` system call.)