# Multiple of 3 using 16 bit Assembler NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

Please can someone help me, I have been researching this for the past few weeks now and I have not found a solution to my problem.

I am trying to determine whether a number entered by a user is a multiple of three or not.
The range of numbers is between 1-9.

Below is the code that I am working on:

```
mov ah,01   
int 21h
mov bl,al
mov bl,3
div bl
cmp ah,0 ;Checks to see if remainder is zero
je e ;if it is not, go to e else execute code below
                
    mov dx, var1
    mov ah,09
    int 21h
    jmp exit
            
e:
    mov dx, var2
    mov ah,09
    int 21h
    jmp exit
        
exit:
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
```

I know that I need to convert my input into hexadecimal, I have tried to use the below line for that but it does not help, when I output the values to be able to see them, I get symbols like a smiley :

```
 add ch,48
```

Comment: basically a duplicate of [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19309749), but that's 32-bit code.  There's probably a 16-bit version somewhere that includes input via DOS or BIOS calls.  (Fun fact: for divisibility by 9, you could use the math trick of summing the base-10 digits (casting out 9s), instead of multiplying and adding to create a binary integer representation of the number.  Either way, at no point is actual hex involved; you don't want to break the number up into 4-bit chunks.)

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to determine whether a number entered by a user is a multiple of three or not. The range of numbers is between 1-9.

> ```
> mov ah,01   
> int 21h
> ```

The input that you get from this DOS function is a **character** represented by an ASCII code. If you've used the keyboard keys <kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>9</kbd>, you will have received in the `AL` register a number ranging from 49 to 57.
To arrive at the **values** depicted on those keys you just need to subtract 48:

```
sub al, 48
```

To check if the number is a multiple of 3, you can indeed divide by 3 and inspect the remainder. But the byte-sized division expects the number that want to divide in the `AX` register and that's something that you've neglected!

```
mov ah, 0  ; From AL to AX (could have used CBW instruction here)
mov bl, 3
div bl     ; Divides AX by BL -> Quotient in AL, Remainder in AH
```

Rest is like you did it...

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I used the code that you have provided for conversion initially but I guess I did not use it in the correct context with the code that followed.