# How to convert string to int in assembly MSVC

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

So, I have a task that I need to convert from string for example string "542215" to int 542215 or with any other ASCII symbols. I am kindof new to assembly programming so, I have almost no clue to what I am doing with it, but I wrote my experimental code.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

int Letters;
    char* argv1 = argv[1];

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Nepateiktas parametras*/\n");
        return(0);
    }
    __asm {

        push eax
        push ebx
        push ecx

        xor ecx, ecx           
        mov eax, argv1  

    NextChar:
        movzx eax, byte ptr [esi + ecx]
        test eax, eax
        jz Done

        push ecx

        sub eax, 48
        push eax
        call PrintIt
        
        pop ecx
        inc ecx
        jmp NextChar
    
    Done:
        pop ecx
        pop ebx
        pop eax

    PrintIt:
        mov[Letters], eax

            pop ecx
            pop ebx
            pop eax

    };

    printf("Count of letters in string %s is %d\n", argv[1], Letters);

    return(0);
}
```

and I am getting error that "Run-time check failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

This error basicly gives me 0 ideas what is going on, or what even ESP is, so any help would be appreciated with my code.

Comment: I don't know x86 assembly to well (I think that's what you're using) but this might be useful for x86 assembly: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309749/nasm-assembly-convert-input-to-integer/19312503#19312503)

Comment: `PrintIt` is not a function, it does not return. Also, you fall through into it.

Comment: Write the code in C, then compile with the option to save the assembler listing ([`/FA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fa-fa-listing-file?view=msvc-160) for MSVC). That will show how the compiler does it, and you can build on it from there.

Answer (score 2):

1. you don't need to push/pop registers around your whole asm statement; MSVC already notices which registers you modify.
2. You're popping the registers twice at the end, when execution falls through from `Done:` to `PrintIt`.  Or even worse, on strings of non-zero length, you're leaving the asm statement via a path of execution that does 3 `push`es at the start, `push ecx`, `push eax`, `call PrintInt`, and then 3 pops.  So one of your register-restores is actually reloading the return address pushed by `call`, and leaving 3 pushed values on the stack.
3. If you don't know that ESP is the stack pointer, one of x86's 8 general-purpose integer registers, you need to continue reading an intro to basic x86 asm before using stack instructions like `push` and `call`.

   Also something about the fact that labels aren't the same thing as functions, and how execution continues to the next instruction.

And BTW, int->string will involve a multiply by 10. See [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309749/nasm-assembly-convert-input-to-integer/49548057#49548057) for the standard algorithm and an asm implementation.

Comment: Why is the OP loading `EAX` (`mov eax, argv1`) instead of `ESI` that they are using (`movzx eax, byte ptr [esi + ecx]`) ?

Comment: @SepRoland: I have no clue, I stopped looking at the details after seeing no multiply, and the total showstopper of `call PrintIt` leaving the asm block, or the other way out of the loop popping twice.. I was going to just comment about needing to understand what the stack is to be able to use asm, but it turned into a minimal answer so I posted it that way.  I have no interest in finding all the bugs in this, but since you mention it the actual loop structure is actually viable if inefficient.  I did link another answer that explains how to do string->integer, no need to repeat myself here.