# How to get keyboard ASCII input and save it to a value in .data in x86_64 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, osdev

So as my question states, how do you get the ASCII key code from keyboard input as an integer value, then I want to save that value in a dataword inside of .data so I can then place the dataword into a different function.

```
input:
    ; get ASCII for keyboard input
    ; save ASCII into cha
    push rbp
    mov rdi, cha
    call kernel_input
    pop rbp

section .data
    cha dw
```

Comment: You could do a `sys_read` to get a single byte from the input stream.

Comment: You tagged this [osdev].  Does that mean you're writing kernel code, specifically a keyboard driver?  (If so, for what hardware?  legacy possibly-emulated PS/2 keyboard controller?  USB (much more complex), or something like UEFI calls to take care of it for you?)  If you're not writing a kernel / bare-metal / uefi application, then you're just going to want to ask the kernel to read input into your memory.  It will be ASCII text representing digits which you can turn into a binary integer with [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548057)

Comment: Also note that `cha dw` reserves no bytes.  Perhaps you mean `section .bss` / `cha resw 1` to reserve 2 bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to store a single byte by calling x64's SYS_READ system call. Here is some modified code based on your example.

```
input:
    ; get ASCII for keyboard input
    ; save ASCII into cha
    push rbp
    mov  rdx, 1             ; max length
    mov  rsi, cha           ; buffer
    mov  rdi, 0             ; stdin
    mov  rax, 0             ; sys_read
    syscall
    pop rbp

section .data
    cha dw 0
```

I recommend looking up [system calls in Linux](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/) for additional details.

Comment: `cha dw` has an empty list of word initializers, so it reserves 0 bytes.  Normally you'd just use stack space for a small fixed size, but you want at least `dw 0`.  Also, one way of reading the question would imply they  want [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548057) to save a binary integer into .data.  And it's not clear if they're actually doing [osdev]; if so they may be trying to write a keyboard driver.