# Could anyone help me to read 64 bit from console in 32 bit RISC-V

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, riscv, bigint, rars-simulator

I am new to assembly, but could anyone teach me how to read 64 bit from console in 32 bit RISC-V?

```
    .eqv SYS_EXITO, 10
    .eqv CON_PRTSTR, 4
    .eqv CON_PRTINT, 1
    .eqv CON_RDINT, 5
    .eqv BUFSIZE, 100
    .data
prompt:
    .asciz "Read 64 bit integer:"
result:
    .asciz "Output:"
    
buf:
    .space BUFSIZE
    .text

main:
    la a0, prompt
    li a7, CON_PRTSTR
    ecall 

    la a0, buf
    li a1, BUFSIZE
    li a7, CON_RDINT
    ecall
```

Then we I input 4294967295, the following error occured.

```
Error in /private/var/folders/bf/t4py6npj0v38grsvrgvq1dx00000gn/T/hsperfdata_sotarosuzuki/riscv1.asm line 24: Runtime exception at 0x00400020: invalid integer input (syscall 5)
```

So, should I read the integers as string and convert it to integer?
I have searched for this solution, but I cannot find it.

Comment: RARS doesn't have 64-bit integer input, even when 64-bit processor setting is enabled!  So, yes, you have to do it yourself from string/text.  RARS also offers virtually no library support, so there's no `atoi` and no `atol`, thus you're really on your own to write that.  You'll want to do the basic arithmetic of an `atol` algorithm in 64-bits which is a minor burden for a 32-bit processor, and @Peter gives a number of suggestions as how to do that.  Further, you may or may not want to check for overflow in 64-bit arithmetic (ideally you would).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, if you can't use the toy system calls, read a string and do `total = total*10 + digit` on it, where `digit = c-'0'`.  You'll need to do extended-precision multiply, so it's probably easier to do extended-precision *shifts* like `(total << 3) + (total << 1)`.

Check compiler output [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAHKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTHxdpgOaUIETMQEGT5%2BXLaY9nkM1bUEBWGR0XG2NXUNWc0KQ93BvcX9sQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzMHI3lgA1CYbbuP4ggB0CIfYJhoAgje3XsEEAGySAPoEe%2BN1S28QXgYKWAIXQe2QCFqACoEnMTAB2Kx3PYovZPQRvT57Ig1WgHDYAET2GkOSNuqLRQLwIMwYPwwEI%2BKJML2AFo9mAOBpOaSKQB6Pl7BKYVrBYDYhCYPY0YjjPaEaJMdryhRohReMS0ACee2AqAw8oYeyYChYDwpAHcEHQpRB6YzDm49lwNHMDoiKXsBXtaPqEpTHHjDDqGAJWfavhDakwHNFzZ6UTixEzsahcVCXQdLHsI6T4wmEtYixsLAmy6jvSyLSbwZLkABrWl7KL8YhSgiSn1%2BvYkH0mr4K4hKtL5z0RlMs9mc7nrEujhEE0dtgjLI1J2h5u4LjgLWicACsvD8XN4qE4biL2YUSxWUs2PFIBE0O4W9ZAkg0Zw28LMGnhXC4ABOfdYliMxv30ThJF4FgJA0DRSGPLRSDPDheAUEAEKfE8FjgWAkDQFgEhtMgKAgQjiPoGJiAANw2MxWR2QxgCkeC%2BDoAhogwiAImfUgImCWotU4B9CLYQQAHkGG1PisBYZjxBPUh8DbSoaMwDClMwVQKi8TiRN4Z5Wj42g8AiIdiC1DwsD4ghiDwWDuB3PgDGABQADU8EwC0JOFY8H34QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQlN0Mx9GYlBLxsUyIgwyAFlQBJ2k01kJI2NlVGQNkAHVNXQ1oKnaFwGHcTxGn8GqeiKEpsmSVIBBGJpEja9omr6GIxgqyoBE6YY6tGFo2iqCY%2BpmAbBi6Tq9HGLpZpargFmvZZVj0OyRQM3cDyPPjUIAJQASSENxWXcvZaPo4AiqYoxnUkM5Pw0PYIAvSxrFIPZcEIXt73%2BjwiJIrN6LmXhsK0OYFklJgsBiCBXxADZP33X94Q2DZJC4MwXjMMx90AyCOGgxCTs4dDMMfZ9cJgRAUFQcGqPISgKJIkB7oYx7kBdX92NoTjZUoXilIE5hLIM0gxMYAgpJkpS5IUtZkJUyq8HUzTkO03T9Kc8hBGMpSUosqyMHVmH7McngFioVyPK8ny/NlwLhFEcQwo9yK1D43RmgMIxEt%2Byx9DMtLUZQrK0hyvKCqK1lStoWhyqm5wIFcJbmkCKZmv6Zocna9Jxq64vevz/rlqG9pRvqMua4zjoZqrublomHOFrqNbC82m8duaPa1nt8nDyppSzsu67bt5x7dWQIqXTOMx3q%2Bn6rHDgH8CIYhIeaPYwco6J9%2Bh%2BmcLRsxALOF1/2AjZAKkYCNEkDZycppDTxp2w6dhl9ybMMdSe38/7w1IOpWUaR3xAA%3D). For example, GCC using shifts, clang using `mul`/`mulhu`(high unsigned) for the `lo * lo` 32x32=>64-bit partial product, and a `mul` for the high half cross product (`hi * lo`).  It's fewer instructions, but depends on a RISC-V CPU with a fast multiplier to be faster than shift/or.

(RISC-V extended-precision addition is inconvenient since it doesn't have a carry flag, you need to emulate carry-out as `unsigned sum = a+b;` `carry = sum<a;`)

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t strtou64(unsigned char*p){
    uint64_t total = 0;
    unsigned digit = *p - '0';    // peeling the first iteration is usually good in asm
    while (digit < 10) {     // loop until any non-digit character
        total = total*10 + digit;
        p++;                // *p was checked before the loop or last iteration
        digit = *p - '0';   // get a digit ready for the loop branch
    }
    return total;
}
```

Clang's output is shorter, so I'll show it.  It of course follows the standard calling convention, taking the pointer in `a0`, and returning a 64-bit integer in a pair of registers, `a1:a0`:

```
# rv32gc clang 14.0  -O3
strtou64:
        mv      a2, a0
        lbu     a0, 0(a0)         # load the first char
        addi    a3, a0, -48       # *p - '0'
        li      a0, 9
        bltu    a0, a3, .LBB0_4   # return 0 if the first char is a non-digit
        li      a0, 0               # total in a1:a0 = 0   ;  should have done these before the branch
        li      a1, 0                           # so a separate ret wouldn't be needed
        addi    a2, a2, 1           # p++
        li      a6, 10              # multiplier constant
.LBB0_2:                            # do{
        mulhu   a5, a0, a6            # high half of (lo(total) * 10)
        mul     a1, a1, a6            # hi(total) * 10
        add     a1, a1, a5            # add the high-half partial products
        mul     a5, a0, a6            # low half of  (lo(total) * 10)
        lbu     a4, 0(a2)                # load *p
        add     a0, a5, a3            # lo(total) =  lo(total*10) + digit
        sltu    a3, a0, a5            # carry-out from that
        add     a1, a1, a3            # propagate carry into hi(total)
        addi    a3, a4, -48             # digit = *p - '0'
        addi    a2, a2, 1                # p++ done after the load; clang peeled one pointer increment before the loop
        bltu    a3, a6, .LBB0_2     # }while(digit < 10)
        ret
.LBB0_4:
        li      a0, 0               # return 0 special case
        li      a1, 0               # because clang was dumb and didn't load these regs before branching
        ret
```

If you want to go with GCC's shift/or strategy, it should be straightforward to see how that slots in to the same logic clang is using.  You can look at compiler output for a function like `return u64 << 3` to see which instructions are part of that.

And BTW, I wrote the C with compiling to decent asm in mind, making it easy for the compiler to transform it into a `do{}while` loop with the condition at the bottom.  I based it on the x86 asm in my answer on [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309749/nasm-assembly-convert-input-to-integer/49548057#49548057)