# Do someone knows how to read an hexadecimal value with RISC-V?

Tags: riscv

I have this code where I need to enter as an int argument an hexadecimal value to return it's coordinates, I use "li a7, 5" for basic int but when I try inputing an hexa like 0x1001010C it dosen't
work (which seems logic since it should be reconized as a string because of the letters). I know I could create a string hexa to int hexa function but isn't there a way to just read the hexa and put it as an int directly ?

I searched for an Environnement call that do this but did'nt find anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could anyone help me to read 64 bit from console in 32 bit RISC-V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238775/could-anyone-help-me-to-read-64-bit-from-console-in-32-bit-risc-v)

Comment: not an exact dup, but think it references the relevant parts.  would help if OP specifies what they mean by "it doesn't work", i.e. what is the actual error message.  note that strings are be enclosed in quotes (`"`) in most languages, so I doubt this would be being interpreted as a string.  you could try a smaller hex value (e.g. `0x10`) and see if you get a decimal value of 16 to see if it's hex support or something else.  note that RISC-V can't natively load full register width values in one instruction, it needs a pair