# NASM | unable to use 3 digit integer from stdin in mathematic operation / at all

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am currently working on a project in an introduction to assembly course in which we are asked to subtract a single digit integer from a three digit integer and display a **two** digit output. (implying the 3 digit integer is > 100 yet < 108)

I seem to be having issues dealing with this variable at every step. I wrote the below program to see if I could put it into the ax 16 bit register and move it back and can't seem to do even that.

I understand there may be an issue with the ascii value of it being larger than 1 byte, although seeing as 'ax' is a 2 byte register it doesn't seem like it would be problematic.

I am using the online rextester.com nasm compiler.

```
section .bss
    input: resb 1
    
section .text
    global _start
    
_start:
    
    mov eax,3
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,input
    mov edx,3
    int 80h
    
    mov [input],ax
    mov ax,[input]
    
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,input
    mov edx,1
    int 80h

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h
```

the output of this is garbage but without the mov I get the first digit of the int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are reading 3 bytes into the buffer `input` which only has space for 1 byte (you wrote `resb 1`).
2. If you type `572` as input to this program, the contents of the `input` buffer will be the three bytes corresponding to the characters `5`, `7` and `2`, whose ASCII character codes are 53, 55, 50 respectively.  It is up to you to write the code to do the math that converts this into the integer 572 for use with arithmetic operations.  In a higher-level language this would be done for you by a library function like `scanf` or `atoi`, but this is assembly and you have to do everything yourself.  See [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309749/nasm-assembly-convert-input-to-integer/49548057) for some examples.
3. `mov [input],ax` would overwrite the input buffer with the contents of `ax`, which is the return value from the `read` system call (i.e. the number of bytes read, likely `3`).  That's not what you want to do.  `mov ax, [input]` by itself is closer as it actually loads the 16-bit value from `input` into `ax`, but as noted, it won't be the desired value because you haven't done the decimal to binary conversion.

Comment: Not sure why I did `mov [input],ax` as I did it correctly earlier, but thank you. I will read the input into 3 bytes and work on conversion from there.
I think what I was thinking is that you could treat the input as a single int despite printing out multi-digit integers requiring a conversion for each using division / a remainder.