# Incorrect results subtracting 1 from 100 working with a string of ASCII digits

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bigint

```
section .bss
num: resb 3
  
section .text
global _start
_start:
 ; Read input
 mov eax, 3
 mov ebx, 0
 mov ecx, num
 mov edx, 3
 int 80h
   
  sub byte [num+2], 1
  cmp byte [num+2], 255
jne skip_borrow
   
   sub byte [num+1], 1
   cmp byte [num+1], 255
jne skip_borrow

   sub byte [num], 1

skip_borrow:
   cmp byte [num], 0
jne skip_carry
   mov byte [num+1], 9
   mov byte [num+2], 9  
skip_carry:      

 mov eax, 4
 mov ebx, 1
 mov ecx, num
 mov edx, 3
 int 80h

 mov eax, 1
 mov ebx, 0
 int 80h
```

The code is reading three digit input number and one digit input number. subtracting one digit number from lower than 100 and higher than 100 works. However, subtracting from 100, 200, 300 is giving wrong output. For example, 100 minus 1 gives me 10/ not 99 or 099 and 200 minus 1 gives me 20/ not 199. How do I solve this issue.

Comment: You're working with *ASCII* digits, not binary integers, so you want to check for going below `'0'` (0x30), not `0` (0x0).

Comment: As you're working with multiple units, you have to implement carry for addition and borrow for subtraction across those multiple units.  If the units are decimal ASCII digits then carry happens with > '9' and borrow when < '0'.  To find the values of '0' and '9' look them up in an ASCII chart.  Alternately, you can convert the ASCII digits to integers 0-9, then check arithmetic for for > 9 and/or < 0, to carry/borrow, and finally convert them back to ASCII digits if that's what you want.

Comment: Typical bigint systems will use integers (whether byte- or word- sized), rather than ASCII digits in storage because when you add/subtract/etc..  two such numbers together, it is easier to do the arithmetic with integers rather than ASCII digits — for example, we can multiply 5x6=30, but to multiply '5' x '6' gives very strange answers: '5' is 53 and '6' is 54; 53 x 54 = 2862,  Conversion from string to integer forms then happens on input and output while internal storage uses an integer form more ready for arithmetic.

Comment: @ErikEidt: I added the [bigint] tag because this implementation choice (of working with separate digits) is effectively that.  IDK if the OP is interested in extending it to work with numbers that wouldn't fit in a register as a 32-bit binary integer.  But yeah, [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19309749) / [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) would be the standard way for integers up to 2^32 - 1

Comment: No [tag:bcd] here.

Comment: @user207421: An array of decimal digits is unpacked BCD.  x86 even has instructions for working with data in that format, like `aad` - ASCII Adjust AL After Subtraction - https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aas - Intel's manual entry describes the relevant data format as "unpacked BCD".  This question isn't attempting to use those instructions, but an answer could instead of doing it manually with `cmp al, '0'` or whatever.  I don't think the question *needs* the [bcd] tag, but that's why I added it originally.  (Along with [bigint], which the OP is trying to do with base-10 limbs.)

Answer (score 1):

> For example, 100 minus 1 gives me **10/** not 99 or 099

The input at *num* is composed of characters '1', '0', and '0'. Their ASCII values are 49, 48, and 48.

> ```
> sub byte [num+2], 1
> cmp byte [num+2], 255
> jne skip_borrow
> ```

Because the `sub` instruction is subtracting 1 from a number in the range [48,57], you get a result in the range [47,56]. So this will never produce the number 255 and therefore the `jne skip_borrow` will always be taken.

Then arriving at *skip_borrow*

> ```
> skip_borrow:
>   cmp byte [num], 0
>   jne skip_carry
>   mov byte [num+1], 9
>   mov byte [num+2], 9  
> skip_carry:
> ```

you were hoping for this part of the code to produce the 99 but that's never going to happen since the condition is never going to be true! The first byte at *num* is an ASCII code in the range [48,57], so never 0 and therefore the `jne skip_carry` will always be taken.

All of the above results in two unmodified bytes followed by one decremented byte (that, if it was '0', will display as '/'). **And this is what is going to happen for any of the 1000 possible inputs**. I would say that the phrase: "subtracting one digit number from lower than 100 and higher than 100 **works**." is proof that you didn't do sufficient testing...

### Solution

Next code decrements a 3-digit ASCII counter with wraparound from '000' to '999':

```
  mov  ecx, num

  dec  byte [ecx + 2]
  cmp  byte [ecx + 2], '0'
  jnb  done
  mov  byte [ecx + 2], '9'

  dec  byte [ecx + 1]
  cmp  byte [ecx + 1], '0'
  jnb  done
  mov  byte [ecx + 1], '9'

  dec  byte [ecx]
  cmp  byte [ecx], '0'
  jnb  done
  mov  byte [ecx], '9'

done:
  mov  edx, 3
  mov  ebx, 1
  mov  eax, 4
  int  80h
```

You can write it as a loop:

```
  mov  eax, 2
more:
  dec  byte [num + eax]
  cmp  byte [num + eax], '0'
  jnb  done
  mov  byte [num + eax], '9'
  sub  eax, 1
  jnb  more

done:
  mov  edx, 3
  mov  ecx, num
  mov  ebx, 1
  mov  eax, 4
  int  80h
```