# GNU AS assembly cannot convert user input to a decimal

Tags: assembly, arm64, gnu-assembler

I am trying to learn assembly by writing a simple calculator in aarch64 assembly (GNU AS) I succeed on prompting user input but I cannot check if the user input is a number or even a char like '+' Here is the code:

```
.global main

.section .data

op_plus: .byte '+'

temp: .skip 1

debug_msg1: .asciz "True"

debug_msg1_len = . - debug_msg1

message_0:

    .asciz "Hello, World!\n"

message_0_len = . - message_0

message_1:

    .asciz "Enter mode +,-,*,/: "

message_1_len = . - message_1

message_2: 

    .asciz "enter the first num: "

message_2_len = . - message_2

message_3: 

    .asciz "enter the second num: "

message_3_len = . - message_3

message_4: 

    .asciz "results is "

message_4_len = . - message_4

.section .bss

    .lcomm num1,10

    .lcomm num2, 10

    operator: .skip 1

.section .text

main:

    // Writes "Hello, world!"

    ldr x1, =message_0  // Load the address of the message

    ldr x2, =message_0_len       // Length of the message

    bl print

    

    /* prompts mode */

    ldr x1, =message_1

    ldr x2, =message_1_len

    bl print

    // takes input

    ldr x1, =operator

    ldr x2, =10

    bl input

    

    ldr w0, [x1]

    /* fake input to handle enter press

    ldr x1, =temp

    ldr x2, =1

    bl input*/

    /* end prompt mode */

    /* prompts first num */

    ldr x1, =message_2

    ldr x2, =message_2_len

    bl print

    

    // takes input

    ldr x1, =num1

    ldr x2, =10

    bl input

    /* end prompt first num */

    /* prompts second num */

    ldr x1, =message_3

    ldr x2, =message_3_len

    bl print

    

    // takes input

    ldr x1, =num2

    ldr x2, =10

    bl input

    ldrb w2,[x1]

    /* end prompt second num */

    //prints operator

    /* results */

    ldr x1, =operator

    

    sub x1, x1, '0'

    //prints x1 to make sure its correct

    ldr x2, =20

    bl print

    

    cmp x1, 1

    

    beq add

    /* end results */

    // Exit the program

    bl exit

print:

    mov x0, 1 // file descriptor STDOUT

    mov w8, 64 // sys call sys write

    svc #0 // invoke syscall

    

    ret // branch back to [lr](in this case its _start)

input: 

    mov x0, 0 // file descriptor STDIN

    mov w8, #63 // syscall sys read

    svc #0

    

    

    ret

succes_res: 

    ldr x1, =message_4

    ldr x2, = message_4_len

    bl print

    ret

add: 

    add w3, w1, w2

    bl succes_res

    bl exit

exit: 

    mov w8, #93 // syscall exit

    mov x0, #0 // exit status

    svc #0

true:

    ldr x1, =debug_msg1

    ldr x2, =debug_msg1_len

    bl print

    ret

exit_err:

    mov w8, #93

    mov x0, #1

    svc #0
```

- converting input to a decimal by doing `sub {register},{register}, '0'` it deletes everything from the register
- directly checking for input by using `cmp {register}, {value}` where value is immediate or not && is in [1,'+'] even tried to make a data to put the value inside like this `op_plus: .ascii "+"`
- removing new line by making input only 1 char long `ldr x2, =1` and taking another fake input to handle enter press...

Comment: Why is this tagged x86-64?  For x86-64, see [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548057) .  Your code is AArch64 so the [arm64] tag is correct.

Comment: If you've correctly loaded an ASCII byte into a register, `cmp w0, '+'` will set flags accordingly, such that `beq` will be taken for example.  Single-step your code in a debugger and check register values.

Comment: 0: I believe GNU Assembler code is the same for both arches the only difference is the register so this code should work for x86-64 with just replaced registers?

Comment: I am not using an ide and I cannot use one I have tried to debug by printing...

Comment: No, x86-64 has different instruction mnemonics, like `movzx eax, byte ptr [rdi]` to do a zero-extending byte load (in GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix`), a lot different from AArch64 `ldrb`.  And x86-64 `call` pushes a return address on the stack, vs. AArch64 `bl` setting `lr` = return address.  Vastly different architectures!

Comment: I don't use an IDE either; I use `gdb ./a.out` on the command line in a terminal window.  Use a debugger; you're wasting your time without one.

Comment: Ok thanks I removed the x86-64 tag

Comment: Oh I didn't know that there is a thing such as command line debugger I will research that thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by doing ldrb instead of ldr
Like this:

```
ldr X1, =operator
ldrb w0, [X1]


ldr X1, =num1
ldrb W1, [X1]
sub w1, w1, '0' // converts to an int
...
cmp w0, '+' //works
```

NOTE: You have to do that at the end because sometimes w registers have the same value as x registers so if an x changed a w can change (not sure why I don't want to provide false information)

```
X1 = value
W1 == value
W1 = another_value
X1 = another_value
X1 = new_value
W1 == new_value
```

Comment: W1 is the low 32 bits of X1.  Writing an X register with a different value will always change the W register, not just sometimes!  W vs. X is how you tell the assembler you want 32 vs. 64-bit operand-size for the same register-number.