# How do i input and add multiple digits number in Assembly? (Nasm v2.15.05)

Tags: assembly, nasm

I've spent my past 4 hours trying to figure out to have an input to read a multiple digit. I have only succeeded only making one but only restricted from (0-9). What should i do?

I tried changing the byte into two but it doesn't affect the program. I tried everything but i still couldnt figure it out.

```
;adding two numbers(user input)

section .data
msg1 db "Enter the first number : ",0xa
len1 equ $ - msg1
msg2 db "Enter the 2nd number : ",0xa
len2 equ $ - msg2

msg3 db "The sum is: "
len3 equ $- msg3

section .bss
num1 resb 2
num2 resb 2 
res resb 2

section .text
global _start
_start :
  
  ;typing the first msg
  mov edx,len1
  mov ecx,msg1
  mov ebx,1 
  mov eax,4
  int 0x80
  
  ;getting the user input for the first number 
  mov edx,2 
  mov ecx,num1
  mov ebx,0 
  mov eax,3
  int 0x80
  
  ;typing the second msg 
  mov edx,len2
  mov ecx,msg2
  mov ebx,1 
  mov eax,4
  int 0x80
  
  ;getting the 2nd user input
  mov edx,2 
  mov ecx,num2
  mov ebx,0 
  mov eax,3
  int 0x80
  
  ; moving the first number to eax register and second number to ebx
  mov eax,[num1]
  sub eax,'0' ; subtract to convert ascii into decimal
  mov ebx,[num2]
  sub ebx,'0'
  
  add eax,ebx
  add eax,'0' ; to convert decimal into ascii again
  
  mov [res],eax ; storing the sum in res memory location
  
  ;typing the third msg 
  mov edx,len3
  mov ecx,msg3
  mov ebx,1 
  mov eax,4
  int 0x80
  
  ;printing the sum
  mov edx,2
  mov ecx,res
  mov ebx,1 
  mov eax,4
  int 0x80
  
  
  
  ;exiting
  mov ebx,0
  mov eax,1 
  int 0x80
```

Comment: You only reserved 2 bytes for each input string, that's only enough room for 1 digit plus the newline the user will normally press to submit their input.  Also, `char - '0'` only works for single digits to convert to a binary integer in a register.  [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19309749)  / [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894)