# IA32 Assembly converting strings using String Primitives

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm a current student taking classes, and I'm having real troubles with this program. Now, I'm not just looking for the answer, as I would legitimately like to understand what is happening, but I have exhausted all of my resources and now here I am. To start off, my program is supposed to take a user generated string of numbers (32-bit max). From there, I need to use LODS* to pull each digit from the string, and convert it to a decimal value, where I then use LODS* to restore back to a second array for future use. After that, I need to re-access that array and re-convert all of the decimal values to their ASCII reprsentations and print them out.

Right now my issue is that whenever I run the program, the LODS* fuction and conversion routine seems to be running just fine, but when it hits the STOS* function, it gets stored into the actual hex memory of the program, and not the array. My professor and his TA's have been unsuccessful in having this make sense to me, so now I'm at the mercy of my peers on the internet.

```
bytesRead   DWORD ?
userVal     BYTE 10 DUP(?)
MulVal      BYTE 10
inArray     DWORD MAXSIZE DUP(?)
outArray    DWORD MAXSIZE DUP(?)


.code
main PROC

    MOV ECX, VALCOUNT        ;VALCOUNT = 10
    MOV EBX, 0
    PUSH OFFSET Intro
    PUSH OFFSET Header
    CALL ProgIntro

    MOV EDI, OFFSET inArray

_getInts:
    PUSH OFFSET promptDec
    PUSH OFFSET userVal
    PUSH OFFSET bytesRead
    CALL ReadVal
    LOOP _getInts

ReadVal PROC

    PUSH EBP
    MOV EBP, ESP
    PUSH ECX

    MOV EDX, [ebp+16]    ;print prompt
    CALL WriteString
    MOV EDX, [ebp+12]    ;set buffer for input
    MOV ECX, MAXSIZE
    CALL ReadString
    MOV bytesRead, EAX
    MOV ECX, bytesRead   ;set counter to number of digits
    MOV ESI, [ebp+12]
    MOV BL, 0
_convLoop:
    CLD
    LODSB
    SUB AL, '0'
    PUSH EAX
    MOV AL, BL
    MUL MulVal
    MOV BL, AL
    POP EAX
    ADD BL, AL
    STOSB
    LOOP _convLoop

    ADD EDI, 4
    POP ECX
    POP EBP
    RET 12

ReadVal ENDP
```

Here's my main and the relevant procedure for anyone who is interested. I look forward to seeing what wisdom you all have to impart on me. Thanks in advance.

Tried inputting a simple string of '1234'. Expected 1234d to be stored in inArray, but was stored in hex memory of program.

Comment: Hmmm, what's the difference of "actual hex memory" and "array"? By the way, note that the value `1234` won't fit in the 8-bit register `BL` (the maximum value is 255).

Comment: When I try to access the data down the line, I can't access the data because it's not stored in the array, it's stored somewhere I can't access it. You also bring up a good point about the data not fitting in BL... that's a second issue I'm going to have to figure out once I get this figured out. considering that I have to access the string bit by bit, LODSB is about all I can use, which means I'm using AL, which means BL is all I can use.

Comment: Actually it seems in my sleep deprived state, I failed to recognize that it is actually storing as intended. I managed to sort out the BL issue, now the trick is telling the machine when to stop iterating when it reaches a spot that has no number

Comment: [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19309749) shows some less clunky code for this problem, BTW.  You don't need or want one-operand `mul` that reads AL and writes the result in AH:AL (aka AX), just use 32-bit `imul eax, eax, 10`.

Answer (score 2):

You claim that `LODSB` and the conversion routine seem to be running just fine, but looks can be deceiving! You're right though that it goes wrong when it hits `STOSB`. That `stos` instruction is meant to store the finished number in the *inArray* (at EDI). This instruction should never be part of the *_convLoop* loop, but follow it. And because the task description states that 32-bit numbers are to be expected, the dword version `stosd` would do the job.

In your comment that says "LODSB is about all I can use, which means I'm using AL, which means BL is all I can use", you show confusion between the size of what you load (which is a single digit fitting in a byte) and the size of what you store (which is the finished number fitting in a dword). Instead of BL, you need to use EBX, and even better would be EDX as that is not a 'call-preserved' register. Of course this also means that you cannot continue to use the byte-sized multiplication. Luckily the x86 instruction set has the `imul` instruction that can easily multiply any general purpose register with a number.

### A solution using string primitives (as it was tasked)

```
  call  ReadString    ; -> EAX (bytesRead)
  mov   esi, [ebp+8]  ; (1) OFFSET bytesRead
  mov   [esi], eax    ; (1)

  xor   edx, edx      ; (2) Number under construction
  mov   esi, [ebp+12] ; OFFSET userVal
  mov   ecx, eax
_convLoop:
  lodsb               ; (3)
  sub   al, '0'       ; Conversion from ["0","9"] to [0,9]
  imul  edx, 10
  movzx eax, al       ; Prepare for same-size operands 
  add   edx, eax      ; This addition needs same-size operands
  dec   ecx           ; (4)
  jnz   _convLoop     ; (4)
  mov   eax, edx      ; (5)
  stosd               ; (5) No more need for `ADD EDI, 4`
```

(1) Since you passed the `OFFSET bytesRead` via the stack, you should not be using *bytesRead* directly.
(2) Equivalent to `mov edx, 0` but much preferred.
(3) You can trust the direction flag (DF) to be clear. No need to use `cld` and especially not repeatedly *in* the loop!
(4) `dec` followed by `jnz` is much better than `loop`.
(5) You could still use `mov [edi], edx` followed by `add edi, 4`.

---

> now the trick is telling the machine when to stop iterating when it reaches a spot that has no number

If the `sub al, '0'` that converts from ["0","9"] to [0,9] actually does not produce [0,9], then you can consider that as having reached the end of the number.
And if it is at all possible that the *bytesRead* value could be zero, then you should not enter the *_convLoop* loop, but probably still return the number zero to the *inArray*.

```
  call  ReadString    ; -> EAX (bytesRead)
  mov   esi, [ebp+8]  ; (1) OFFSET bytesRead
  mov   [esi], eax    ; (1)

  xor   edx, edx      ; (2) Number under construction
  test  eax, eax
  jz    _endLoop
  mov   esi, [ebp+12] ; OFFSET userVal
  mov   ecx, eax
_convLoop:
  lodsb               ; (3)
  sub   al, '0'       ; Conversion from ["0","9"] to [0,9]
  cmp   al, 9
  ja    _endLoop      ; Was not a decimal digit
  imul  edx, 10
  movzx eax, al       ; Prepare for same-size operands 
  add   edx, eax      ; This addition needs same-size operands
  dec   ecx           ; (4)
  jnz   _convLoop     ; (4)
_endLoop:
  mov   eax, edx      ; (5)
  stosd               ; (5) No more need for `ADD EDI, 4`
```

Comment: If you `xor eax,eax` ahead of the loop (right after `mov ecx, eax`), `lodsb` / `sub al, '0'` produces a zero-extended result you can use with `add edx, eax`.  It won't have a partial-register stall even on P6-family CPUs, unless an interrupt handler saves/restores the registers between the XOR-zeroing and end of the loop.  And on other CPUs, the loop-carried dependency chain through EAX will only be 2 cycles long (merge a new low byte, subtract) instead of 3 (also movzx eax, al), letting out-of-order exec get more of that work out of the scheduler to make room for later independent work.