# Newtons Raphson Iteration issues

Tags: function, loops, assembly, infinite-loop, masm

I am writing a 8bit integer newton raphson function in MASM X8086-32bit assembly and I think I am stuck in an infinite loop. The editor I have to use for class does not send an error for infinite loops.

Anyways I am not sure where my problem is. I just started MASM a few weeks ago and am kind of lost any help with the infinite loop would be appreciated. My initial x value is defined as 1.

The function is y = 1/2(x+n/x) ===> x/2+ n/2x where n is the number in question. and x is the intitialized value and then the previous iterations y value.

```
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, prompt  ;Prompt User
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h         ;User input
    sub al, 30h

    mov bh, al
    mov bl, x       ;Loading for loop
    mov al, x

    iteration:
                mul bl; al*bl = al

                mov dl, al ; storing x^2

                add al, 01h ; (x+1)^2
                mul al

                cmp bh, dl
                jge doneCheck ; bh - dl ====> n- x^2 => 0
                doneCheck:
                cmp bh, al; bh-al = ? ====>n - (x+1)^2 == -int
                jl done

                mov al, 02h; loading 2 in ah
                mul bl  ; bl*al = 2(bl) = 2x = al

                shr bl, 1 ; x/2 = bl

                mov cl, al ; storing 2x in cl
                mov ah, 0 ; clearing ah
                mov ch, 0; clearing ch
                mov al, bh ; moving n into ax for division prep
                div cx ; ax/cl ====> n/2x ===> p =ah and q = al

                add bl, ah ;so this is finally 1/2(x+(n/x)) === (x/2+n/2x) y the new value y is now stored in bl for next loop
                mov al, bl ; for next loop
                jmp iteration

    done:

    mov dl, bl; print square root
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
```

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
shl bl, 1 ; x/2 = bl
```

shouldn't be?:

```
shr bl,1
```

-- Updated:

And about your question:

```
BH = Number to find sqrt. When x^2 == BH then x is the sqrt(n)
AL and BL = y value of the last iteration
```

and you do:

```
mul bl     ; AL*BH => AX
cmp bh, al ; BH == AL? or with names: n == x^2 ?
```

**Why the infinite loop?**:

As you take the input with [AH=01h+int 21h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah01), you only read **one char** and you get the [ascii code](http://ascii.cl/) in AL.

Let's assume the user input number is "A", which is translated into the number **65**. By no means, any integer will give you x^2 = 65, so that loop will loop forever.

**I suggest you to use this condition as the loop break**. The result will be an approximation (rounded to the lower number):

```
(n >= x^2) && (n < (x+1)^2)
```

Bear in mind that you are working all with 8 bits, so the highest solution would be: y = 15. Look at this:

```
1^2 = 1
2^2 = 4
3^2 = 9
4^2 = 16
5^2 = 25
6^2 = 36
7^2 = 49
8^2 = 64
...
15^2 = 225
```

Those are the **only** numbers you can calculate sqrt with your code **(without my proposal)**.

So you can only press the following keys as input:

```
$ = number 36
1 = number 49
@ = number 64
Q = number 81
d = number 100
y = number 121
```

Any keypress between those will make your code get into an infinite loop.

And a tip for **output**: add 48 to BL before printing it so it goes to an ASCII number :)

-- Update 2 :

From your code I found this errors:

```
add al, 01h ; (x+1)^2 ; AL = x^2, therefore you are doing (x^2)+1
mul al
```

and here the execution flow will execute all lines always:

```
cmp bh, dl
jge doneCheck ; bh >= dl? ====> n >= x^2 ?
doneCheck:
cmp bh, al; bh-al = ? ====>n - (x+1)^2 == -int
jl done
```

I guess it should be something like:

```
  cmp bh, dl     ; n vs x^2
  jb notSolution ; BH < DL? ====> if n < x^2 continue with next NR step
  cmp bh, al     ; here, n >= x^2
  jb done        ; BH < AL ? ====> if n < (x+1)^2 we found a solution

notSolution:     ; n is not in [ x^2 , (x+1)^2 )
```

I used `jb` instead of `jl` because I assume only possitive numbers. `jl` will treat 129 as a negative number and maybe we will be in trouble.

-- Update 3:

From [Peter Cordes'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40335229/582789) answer, a detail I didn't notice (I read `div cl`):

> div cx ; ax/cl ====> n/2x ===> p =ah and q = al. That would be correct if you'd used div cl

Comment: thanks. Changed that because your right but doesnt fix the infinite loop.

Comment: I took a further look into your code and found why it loops forever :)

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: So i updated my condition statement and am still getting an infinite loop or my user input isnt getting stored correctly. I subtracted 30h from the character accepted?

Comment: maybe i should try pushing my y values onto the stack and then retrieving the last in on the next loop? this way i am not complicating the function by trying to store the proper values in registers before the next iteration?

Comment: Surely using the stack, using the heap or writing it in C will be handy ;) I updated my answer showing some faults in your updated code.

Comment: It does not make sense to subtract 30h from the character accepted. How you read the input is by itself wrong: you can only read alphanumeric ASCII numbers. But the good point is that it is an easy reading. To read a number as several keypresses, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868226/reading-a-number-using-int-21h-dos-8086-assmebly . But first, make it work with the input as you have now :)

Comment: If you wish to use the stack, use it :) but you still have DH left. It is a good practice to write what is each register for :)

Comment: thanks for all the help!! going to try and work these kinks out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you've correctly understood that MUL and DIV have one operand each that's [double the width of the other two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464879/when-and-why-do-we-sign-extend-and-use-cdq-with-mul-div).

Your comments on those lines are wrong:

- `mul bl; al*bl = al`: no, `AX = AL*BL`.
- `div cx ; ax/cl ====> n/2x ===> p =ah and q = al`.  That would be correct if you'd used `div cl`, but DIV r/m16 takes DX:AX as a 32-bit dividend, and produces results in AX=quotient, DX=remainder.

Look up MUL and DIV [in the manual](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/).

---

I highly recommend single-stepping through your code in a debugger.  And/or stopping it in a debugger after it gets into an infinite loop, and single step from there while watching registers.

The bottom of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki has some tips on using GDB to debug asm.  (e.g. use `layout reg`).  Since you're using MASM, you might be using Visual Studio, which has a debugger built in.

It doesn't matter what debugger you use, but it's an essential tool for developing asm.

Comment: Oh. First time I read about a debugger for asm. I never used one! xD Oh, my! xD. Yeah, it is an essential tool. I wish I thought about that long time ago...